# ValueError in Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, function, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I put together the following function that read csv, train the model and predict the request data.

I've got the following ValueError :  Column ordering must be equal for fit and for transform when using the remainder keyword

The training data and the data used for prediction has exact the same number of column , e.g., 15. I am not sure how the "ordering" of the column could have changed.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-280f8d45f523> in <module>
----> 1 safety_project_full(request)

<ipython-input-50-a9c672da1a70> in safety_project_full(request)
     74 
     75     df_resp = pd.DataFrame(data=request_data)
---> 76     response = rf.predict(df_resp)
     77 
     78     output = {"Safety Rating": response[0]}

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    114 
    115         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 116         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    117         # update the docstring of the returned function
    118         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    417         Xt = X
    418         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 419             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    420         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    421 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in transform(self, X)
    581             if (n_cols_transform >= n_cols_fit and
    582                     any(X.columns[:n_cols_fit] != self._df_columns)):
--> 583                 raise ValueError('Column ordering must be equal for fit '
    584                                  'and for transform when using the '
    585                                  'remainder keyword')

ValueError: Column ordering must be equal for fit and for transform when using the remainder keyword
```

Function:

```
    def safety_project_full(request):

    df = pd.read_cdv('a.csv')

    # Define the Features and Target Columns
    features_col = df.drop("y", 1)
    target_col = df["y"]

    # Split the data for training and testing purposes
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features_col, target_col, test_size=0.1)

    # Data Transformed
    numeric_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64']).columns
    categorical_features = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).drop(['y'], axis=1).columns

    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
            ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

    #Putting data transformation and the model in a pipeline
    rf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                         ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(
                                            n_estimators=500,
                                            criterion="gini",
                                            max_features="sqrt",
                                            min_samples_leaf=4))])

    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    request_data = {'A': [request.A],
                    'B': [request.B],
                    'C': [request.C],
                    'D': [request.D],
                    'E': [request.E],
                    'F': [request.F],
                    'G': [request.G],
                    'H': [request.H],
                    'I': [request.I],
                    'J': [request.J],
                    'K': [request.K],
                    'L': [request.L],
                    'M': [request.M],
                    'N': [request.N],
                    'O': [request.O]}

    df_resp = pd.DataFrame(data=request_data)
    response = rf.predict(df_resp)

    output = {"Safety Rating": response[0]}

    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has resolved by adding the specific columns that I used to train x in the df_resp.